# Is there a good method to create a keyword cloud in Ubuntu?

Tags: cloud, tagging

So I have a pretty big server full of all sorts of Open/Office files, engineering data and whathaveyou and I was looking for a good way to index all of the data and create a tag or keyword cloud. Is there any sort of tool do so something like this in Ubuntu? It would save me a ton of time in digging around and rooting out old files...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you want a graphical tool that expands upon 'grep'

For example, say I'm in a folder called 'Documents' and I want to search through all the directory and all the subdirectories for files that contain the word 'event'. Then I can do:

```
grep -r -l "event" *
```

more on grep can be found by typing 'man grep' in a terminal window.

AFAIK, no graphical tool exists to do specifically what you want. But such tools can be created. Can you give a more detailed description of what you want to do?